# How can i access to variable from another js file in react-native

Tags: react-native, variables

I am new in react native. This is a part of App.js

```
<Button
    title="LOGIN"
    onPress={() => 
        {
         {{this.componentDidMount(this.state.city)}}
        }
    }
/>
```

I want to send the "this.state.city" to my other js file "Form.js".

And this is 'Form.js'

```js
import React from 'react';
import { FlatList, ActivityIndicator, Text, View  } from 'react-native';

class Form extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state ={ isLoading: true}
  }
  componentDidMount(){
    const api_key="there_is_an_api_key";
    const city="ankara"
    // I want that variable here
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: As I noticed this question is already asked and answered but in a different title. Please read following question and try to understand it your self. It is always good to put some effort for researching asking a question.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48990513/how-to-pass-state-of-one-component-to-another-in-react-native